# Issue to pass data from activity to fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a problem when i pass arraylist from activity to fragment...i need to see only listivew with checkbox selected (taking id from arraylist) while i see list view before take id and list view after taken id from arraylist...

I show my problem with pics and with code.

with pic:

**before pass data**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yx4xa.png)

**after pass data** 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPme3.png)

with code:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putIntegerArrayList("oki", hm);

        MyListFragment fragment = new MyListFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);


        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);

        transaction.commit();
```

bundle code to get data:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         bundle = getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {

            strtext=bundle.getIntegerArrayList("oki");
            System.out.println("PARAM:"+strtext);
        }
}
```

Who can help me?
thanks everybody!

Comment: Where is the code for retrieve data from bundle?

Comment: ArrayList is String type or CustomType like Model Type Array list ?

Comment: @ManojSrivastava arraylist contains id of checkbox to checkked so in integer type

Answer (score 0):

please refer this

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putStringArrayList("valuesArray", namesArray);
namesFragment myFragment = new namesFragment();
myFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

and in Fragment onCreateView method:

```
  @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String strtext = getArguments().getStringArryList("valuesArray");    
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

Comment: String strtext = getArguments().getStringArryList("valuesArray");    
 make me crash app....

Comment: i put in try catch block     String strtext = getArguments().getStringArryList("valuesArray");    
 so app doesn't crash but getArguments() doesn't get arguments.....so arraylist is empty

Comment: FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);

        transaction.commit(); in this way data is passed but fragment is overlapped on fragment......

Answer (score 0):

It is not issue of the passing data between activity to fragment. Issue is that Fragment is overlapped on another fragment.

Set background color white to parent root of the fragment(each fragment so in future this type of issue never occurs).

This will resolved your issue.

Comment: yes, Fragment is overlapped on another fragment.....now i try to set background white as you advice me...

Comment: How can i know without seeing the code? Please post your code here so every one can check.

Comment: i create another question to explain my new problem?

Comment: with your advice tabs not scroll because with background white fragment overlapped on others fragments